# Prevent Menu From Closing When User Clicks the Input

Tags: css, reactjs, input, chakra-ui

Is there a way to make it so that the `<Input />` doesn't close on click? Currently, if I click inside the input, the menu just closes. I have the same setup as the original poster. I've tried playing around with `closeOnSelect="false"` and that didn't seem to work. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Here is the example in CodeSandbox form:
https://codesandbox.io/s/chakra-menuitem-as-input-forked-9ue4n

```js
import {
  Box,
  Button,
  ChakraProvider,
  Input,
  Menu,
  MenuButton,
  MenuItem,
  MenuList,
  useMenuItem,
} from '@chakra-ui/react';
import React from 'react';

const navigationKeys = ['ArrowUp', 'ArrowDown', 'Escape'];

const MenuInput = props => {
  const { role, ...rest } = useMenuItem(props);
  return (
    <Box px="3" role={role}>
      <Input
        placeholder="Enter value"
        size="sm"
        {...rest}
        onKeyDown={e => {
          if (!navigationKeys.includes(e.key)) {
            e.stopPropagation();
          }
        }}
      />
    </Box>
  );
};

function App() {
  return (
    <ChakraProvider>
      <Menu>
        <MenuButton as={Button}>Button</MenuButton>
        <MenuList>
          <MenuInput />
          <MenuItem>Option 1</MenuItem>
          <MenuItem>Option 2</MenuItem>
        </MenuList>
      </Menu>
    </ChakraProvider>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: add `onClick={e => e.stopPropagation()}` to `<Input/>` element

Comment: That's it! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Add `closeOnSelect={false}` to the menu component to stop the menu closing when clicking on the `MenuInput`.

```js
<Menu closeOnSelect={false}>
        <MenuButton as={Button}>Button</MenuButton>
        <MenuList>
          <MenuInput />
          <MenuItem>Option 1</MenuItem>
          <MenuItem>Option 2</MenuItem>
        </MenuList>
      </Menu>
```

Comment: That's what I originally thought - seems like a good solution, but it doesn't work. Adding onClick={e => e.stopPropagation()} to the <Input/> element did the trick for me.

Comment: awesome glad you found an answer.